# Get "connection refused error" during creating GCP Cluster Node

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

When I create a GKE Cluster

The cluster can be created but the node cannot start properly. Inside the log - Serial port 1 (console) output of a node (vm), I can see following errors:

```
[   24.630930] configure.sh[1010]: Getting the service account access token configured for VM. 
[   24.673381] configure.sh[1010]: Service account access token is received. Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/gke-release/npd-custom-plugins/v1.0.4/npd-custom-plugins-v1.0.4.tar.gz using this token. 
[   24.969664] configure.sh[1116]: curl: (7) Failed to connect to storage.googleapis.com port 443 after 292 ms: Connection refused 
[   24.969859] configure.sh[1116]: Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 10 seconds. 6 retries.
[   66.167634] configure.sh[1116]: Warning: left. 
[   76.459028] configure.sh[1116]: curl: (7) Failed to connect to storage.googleapis.com port 443 after 281 ms: Connection refused 
[   76.459198] configure.sh[1116]: Warning: Problem : connection refused. Will retry in 10 seconds. 1 retries 
[   76.459252] configure.sh[1116]: Warning: left. 
[   86.759856] configure.sh[1116]: curl: (7) Failed to connect to storage.googleapis.com port 443 after 290 ms: Connection refused 
[   86.760211] configure.sh[1010]: == Failed to download https://storage.googleapis.com/gke-release/npd-custom-plugins/v1.0.4/npd-custom-plugins-v1.0.4.tar.gz. Retrying.
```

It looks a permission issue, but I don't really know what permission missed. I even gave editor, network admin,  and security admin to those service account, but still get same error.

```
service-abcde@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Compute Network User

Compute Network Admin
Compute Security Admin
Kubernetes Engine Host Service Agent User
Service Networking Service Agent


abcde@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com

Compute Network User
```

The command I used is:

```
gcloud container clusters create poc-65 --project project-xyz \
  --zone=us-west1-a --enable-ip-alias \
  --network projects/project-xyz/global/networks/network-xyz \
  --subnetwork projects/project-xyz/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/subnet-xyz \
  --services-secondary-range-name uat-xyz-service \
  --cluster-secondary-range-name uat-xyz-pod \
  --no-enable-master-authorized-networks \
  --master-ipv4-cidr 172.16.2.32/28 \
  --enable-private-nodes --num-nodes 3 \
  --default-max-pods-per-node 20
```

Thanks

Comment: command I used : gcloud container clusters create poc-65 --project project-xyz --zone=us-west1-a --enable-ip-alias --network projects/project-xyz/global/networks/network-xyz --subnetwork projects/project-xyz/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/subnet-xyz --services-secondary-range-name uat-xyz-service --cluster-secondary-range-name uat-xyz-pod --no-enable-master-authorized-networks --master-ipv4-cidr 172.16.2.32/28 --enable-private-nodes --num-nodes 3--default-max-pods-per-node 20

Comment: More than a permission error the logs suggest that the nodes cannot connect to GCS. I suspect this happens when the nodes are trying to pull the images. Since it is a private cluster, can you verify the nodes can connect to GCS? Possibly you've not activated Private Google Access in the subnet, there is a Firewall rule or a route misconfigured.

Comment: Thanks, I do enabled "Private Google Access" for the subnet, and our network admin has disabled the 0.0.0.0/0 to default internet gateway of this VPC (Let's say VPC-A), instead of pointing to a router on-prem. Not sure if that's the reason. The error message "Connection refused" really confused me, I am not sure if it's a permission issue, or a route/fire wall issue, since the funny thing is, the VPC (let's say VPC-B) also peered with anther VPC, which also redirect all traffic to the VPC-A. But I have no problem to create cluster from VPC-B.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the cause. Our agency has a policy all traffic to outside have to go through on-prem network, and we do replace the default 0.0.0.0/0 route to pointing it to on-prem. But the firewall rules on-prem block the traffic, that's why during creating the cluster, the node is not able to access google private services APIs. After adjust the firewall rules, the issue is fixed.